# How to read Fortran code from a Fortran punch card

Tags: fortran

I found some "Fortran Papers" (please forgive me I don't know what to call them) which are produced in USSR in 1980s. What I mean by "Fortran Paper" is a paper with numbers and some holes on it. How I know it is Fortran? Well I saw 'em on a video about history of Fortran (I'm still not sure actually). And the "person" who gave me these told me that these are "Fortran Papers" (he called it this way, blame him). So how you read those?

I tried to google (bing) it out but they are not called "Fortran Papers" and I might be on the wrong spot about this. I know there are some genius people on StackOverflow who already know how to read it most efficient way. I'm just kind of seeking for help. This how it somewhat looks like:

[Not the original "paper" I have but still looks something like this. Forgive me, I could not upload the ones I have (no webcam)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo58K.png)

Comment: That is a partial image of a punch card, which contains one line of Fortran code.  Each column represents one EBCDIC character.  The code is called [Hollerith code](https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~jones/cards/codes.html).

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the point of asking whether something is Fortran, but show a picture of something completely different. If you want to know whether the card encodes Fortran, please show the card; if you want to ask how to decode a punch card, that's a different question, and probably better on a site about retro-computing.

Comment: Google "punch card decoder". There appear to be quite a lot of sites which claim to be able to decode them purely from images. Are you sure that trying to use soviet code from the Cold-War era is a great idea, though?

Comment: Not strictly off-topic, but on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com it would be much better with more feedback. If you do post there, delete it here.